# Perform javascript when an input in Customizer is selected/focused?

Tags: customization, jquery

Can't figure out how to perform actions with javascript/jquery when a input is focused/selected in the Customizer under a section. I want to modify the content on the site in the preview when the input is focused.

Is this possible?

I know what my custom input is called under my custom section:

```
$('#_customize-input-checkin\\[title\\]').focus(function() {
        alert( "Handler for .focus() called." );
});
```

But I cannot manage to make it fire?

Comment: Managed to make the alert work. But I am not able to perform actions inside the iframe.

Comment: You need to make use of the [Customizer js API](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/customize-api/the-customizer-javascript-api/). Even thought you can target each element using jQuery, it is more reliable to use the API so, for example, when changing a setting that has a [transport postMessage](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/customize-api/tools-for-improved-user-experience/#using-postmessage-for-improved-setting-previewing) the preview updates.